# Returning OData count for non-entity set collections

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an action routed that returns a non-entity collection.

```
ActionConfiguration previewInvoices = this.EntityType.Collection.Action("PreviewInvoices");
previewInvoices.ReturnsCollection<InvoicePreviewComponent>();
```

Now when I query to get the results, I am using a `$take=20` to control paging through javascript. However it doesn't return a count as it does with entity sets with `$inlinecount=allpages`.

One solution I had been doing was to change the lines to:

```
ActionConfiguration previewInvoices = this.EntityType.Collection.Action("PreviewInvoices");
previewInvoices.ReturnsCollectionFromCollection<InvoicePreviewComponent>("InvoicePreviewComponent");
```

However this generates ghost entity sets in the `$metadata`, which I am using to generate the javascript models and requests. Not ideal, and ultimately not correct to annotate this as an entity set.

How can I modify the response JSON formatter to give the count as requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count value of non-entity collection won't be serialized into the response body.

But you can get the count value by the following code:

```
response.RequestMessage.ODataProperties().TotalCount
```

*(Note: ODataProperties() is an extension method in static class* System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestMessageExtensions)

Comment: Is there no way I can force it to be serialized into the response body? It seems strange behaviour.

Comment: OData can't serialize the count value for non-entity collection now because there is no "Count" property in ODataCollectionValue unlike ODataFeed(used to serialize entity collection). It is an issue with OData.

Comment: Check the odata json spec, it seems that odata.count only supports the count of a collection of entities or a collection of entity references. http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html#_Toc372793054

Comment: Thanks. Seems like quite an oversight. In my scenario I am transforming an entityset to get aggregate data. I suppose once aggergates are supported it will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by an action filter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Use this attribute whenever total number of records needs to be returned in the response in order to perform paging related operations at client side.
/// </summary>
public class PagedResultAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionExecutedContext"></param>
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null&& actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode==System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {                
            dynamic responseContent=null;
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response.Content != null)
                responseContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().Result;
            var count = actionExecutedContext.Response.RequestMessage.ODataProperties().TotalCount;
            var res = new PageResult<dynamic>() {TotalCount=count,Items= responseContent };

            HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage();
            message.StatusCode = actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode;

            var strMessage = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            message.Content = strMessage;
            actionExecutedContext.Response = message;               
        }           
    }
}
```

And the custom PageResult class is:

```
public class PageResult<T>
{      
    public long? TotalCount { get; set; }
    public T Items { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
[PagedResult]
[EnableQuery()]
```